# Using SQLite for unit testing a mysql migrations setup

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, unit-testing, laravel-5

I want to use SQLite for PHPunit tests. We are using the `mysql` driver, so we have created our migrations based on that... meaning we are using `nullables` for default values. `MYSQL` doesn't care about this. `SQLite`, apparently, does.

**Migrations:**

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('username', 132)->nullable();
```

**TestCase snippet:** configuring phpunit environment

```
    $app['config']->set('database.connections.testbench', [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => ''
        ]
```

Running `phpunit` outputs:

> Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL

I noticed there was a "[STRICT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)" mode for `mysql` in the `database.php` configuration file that you can set to `false` which handles invalid or missing data types:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
         ...
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

So I started looking for a `strict` mode for SQLite and found [Strict Mode](http://www.sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=StrictMode) here, tried setting `PRAGMA strict=ON;` to off

```
    $app['config']->set('database.connections.testbench', [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'strict'   => false
        ]
```

But this did not fix it.

Is there a way to set SQLite to ignore `nullable()` values set in migrations (aimed at mysql configurations) so I can run my unit tests quickly with SQLite in memory?

**My alternatives are:**

- remove all `nullable()` options for migrations and add defaults, which will take forever
- use mysql instead of sqlite, which will be much slower

Comment: That sqlite wiki page says that `PRAGMA strict=ON;` is just a suggestion that has been raised. I'm running into the same issue.